# Print in HTML row by row SQL results without storing in memory all rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In PHP (old days) you used `mysql_fetch_assoc` to print something on html, row by row.
Basically tou were making a loop over some sql results without storing whole result in memory.

I have a situation when I'm making a really big query, which "joins" all required tables to make a big row so when I request, for example, an associated model, the query doesn't call the database because data is considered "cached".

The biggest problem of this query, it's that is huge, it loads a lot of things into memory.
Because is built with joins, I really do not require to load all data of all used tables at once in memory, because every row is directly printable (thanks to this join), so my idea was basically to make a loop on each fetched row and print directly it, then discard.

How can I achieve such a thing?

This is a rough table structure I'm using (not completed):

```
Trips
  - has_many Hikers
  - belongs_to Organization

Hikers
  - belongs_to PersonalRecord

PersonalRecord

Organization
  - has_many Trips
```

My join simply take all trips and joins every row of this table with organization, hikers and personal records.

**Update 1:**

Currently I'm using this query to fetch results:

```
table_join_to_cache = '
  INNER JOIN organizations    ON organizations.id         = trips.organization_id
   LEFT JOIN cities           ON cities.id                = trips.city_id
   LEFT JOIN hiker_trips      ON hiker_trips.trip_id      = trips.id
   LEFT JOIN hikers           ON hikers.id                = hiker_trips.hiker_id
   LEFT JOIN personal_records ON personal_records.id      = hikers.personal_record_id
   LEFT JOIN trip_trip_levels ON trip_trip_levels.trip_id = trips.id
   LEFT JOIN trip_levels      ON trip_levels.id           = trip_trip_levels.trip_level_id
'
@trips = Trip.joins(table_join_to_cache)
             .where('trips.begin_date >= ? AND trips.begin_date <= ?', begin_of_month, end_of_month)
             .uniq.order('begin_date ASC, title ASC')
```

And I optionally add other conditions if I require for example, trip for a specific organization.

**N.B.** I would like to avoid pagination if possible.

**My idea:** In my imagination, this should work like a "Cursor", I make the query, than store something like `@trips_cursor = myquery` and then in view `trips_cursor.each_row do |trip|` will create a model object (and discard it) each time is required in loop. It can obviusly be readonly.

**I require ruby on rails code, not PHP**

**UPDATE TO THE ANSWER**

Since I've learnt something meanwhile I would like to share some info I've found.
First, if you use AR queries (where, joins, limit and some similar methods), query **will not run** (lazy loaded) until you run a method, on the query, which is not an *AR method*. Basically every `each` method will fire the query. If you, so, execute `find_each(batch_size: 1)`, on an AR query not fired, it will only load a single row in memory and print that out each time, preserving your valuable RAM. Notice that I used this approach only because, thanks to my giant join, I loaded everything needed and all records are unique, so I don't require them to be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

I think what you're asking for is the `find_each` method. It defaults to loading 1000 rows at a time which is probably ok, but you can configure it to fetch less or more.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I read about this, what I don't understand is how can I print this part in my view and the other problem is that my query is quite complicated, I don't know if I can build it through a find method.

Comment: I believe this works on any `ActiveRecord::Relation`. In other words anything you build and don't call `:all` or `:each`. Calling `:all` forces the query and causes it to become an `Array`. Calling `:each` executes and causes it to become an `Enumerator`. There are probably other methods that force the query, but these are probably the most common ones.

Comment: Actually, the normal `find` methods also force queries.

Comment: Yea my idea is using something like an enumerator, so find_each can be effectively in this case. However, how do I avoid breaking MVC by doing the query on the controller (or model) instead on writing it on the view? Maybe something like `find_each(@parameters_built_on_controller)` ?

Comment: Actually, your controller just needs to set up the appropriate relation (which yours does for `@trips`), then you can process it in your view like omarvelous suggested in his answer. This breaks the rule that the view should not call the model, but I think this is a case where the alternative is worse. If the view can't access the model, then you have to execute the query in the controller. By breaking the rule, the view can decide how much data it wants to display.

Comment: Mh yea, looks a reasonable situation where I can break the rule. I think I were looking for something like an iterator over rows just because that was a good way to avoid breaking it, but yea, I think it's not that useful at this point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Example using find_each or find_in_batches (might be better) if @trips is a relation in the view:

```
<%= @trips.find_in_batches do |trips| %>
  <%= render partial: trips %>
<% end %>
```

How's that?

ALSO, If the results are really that large, I highly recommend you think about using some form of caching like ActiveSupport::Cache::Store: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store

Comment: This is interesting, I'm testing it. Just a question: Should I build the entire query directly in the view?

Comment: No, build the relation/query in the controller and set it as the variable as you are currently doing it.

Comment: Updated the answer with find_in_batches, and Cache tip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many clever solutions but why not to use good old LIMIT in the SQL query? Just fetch 500 rows process them and go for more.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I would like to avoid Pagination for multiple reasons.

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails, sorry to confuse you.

Comment: oh sorry, I was convinced this is PHP related ;-)